# add parent to jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<tr step="step2" optional="true"><td>Gender</td></tr>
<tr step="step2" optional="true">
     <td>
         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
             <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Both the tr's are hidden initially and when a condition is met I want to show the radio button list and the header for which I have to show both the tr's

I have a reference to the rblGender. How do I select all the other elements?

`$("#rblGender").parent().parent().prev()` selects only the first tr. Do I have to add each element one by one? Or is there a way to add the whole chain at once?

Comment: Have you thought about giving the TRs IDs or a common dummy CSS class that will allow you to select both?

Comment: That way I would have to give id's or css classes for all similar controls on the page. and then hard code the id's or classes. Felix solution works the way I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not really understand what you mean with headers, but I assume you want to show both rows. You can use [`.andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

> Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set.

```
$("#rblGender").closest('tr').prev().andSelf()
```

---

You should also use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of a `parent()` chain. It makes it more robust against structural changes (and more readable imho).

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.8, `andSelf()` has been replaced with [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping the `tr` elements in a `tbody` element, and then you only have to navigate to (and hide/show) a single element?

This would be more flexible, because it would allow as many rows as you like to be hidden/shown at the same time.

You will, of course, then need to add some `tbody` elements to the other rows of the table, but this wouldn't make the markup incorrect in any way.

Comment: Well, it is a smart approach but would have had to change the markup. Felix Kling's solution is simpler.